# Apache reload can't updated environment variable?

Tags: apache

I have put this variable in my /etc/init.d/apache2,

```
export VAR1=https
```

And this in the configuration file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

RewriteCond %{ENV:VAR1}  https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule  ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I want to do a rewrite when VAR1 is set to be https. If I update the VAR1 value in the init.d/apache2, then do

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

It works as it should. But if I only do

```
 /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

it seems the new VAR1 value won't be 'seen or noticed' by apache...

So, do I must restart apache or it's possible to just do reload?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

reload wait all process to finish (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/apache/restart-apache/)

restart do not wait process to finish.

Try waiting a minute after reload.

Comment: could you define "while" ? All request send to server must finish, then Apache is restarted

Comment: I wasn't able to get `reload` to work in a container. I had to restart, but then that messed the entrypoint script up, so it ultimately didn't work for me, outside of restarting the container.